# What the time complexity of DigitalRoot?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

Example 1:
Input:
n = 1
Output:  1
Explanation: Digital root of 1 is 1

Example 2:
Input:
n = 99999
Output: 9

Explanation: Sum of digits of 99999 is 45
which is not a single digit number, hence
sum of digit of 45 is 9 which is a single
digit number.

Could someone help what is the time complexity of my code? I think its O(loglog(N)) but not sure.

```
def sumOfDigits(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(n%10) + sumOfDigits(n//10)
        

def digitalRoot(n):
    ans = n
    if n<=9:
        return n
    else:
        while ans>9:
            ans = sumOfDigits(ans)
            
        return ans
```

Comment: 1) What makes you think the complexity of `digitalRoot` is `O(log(log(n))`? 2) What do you think is the complexity of the function `sumOfDigits`?

Comment: Bonus question: Do you know about modular arithmetic, and specifically, do you know something really cool about modulo 9?

Comment: for sumOfDigits time complexity is O(log(n)).

Comment: That's correct; and digitalRoot calls `sumOfDigits` repeatedly. The value of variable `ans` diminishes very fast, so the first call will be the longest. In the first call, `ans == n`. Hence the first call to `sumOfDigits` already costs `log(n)` operations. Note that `log(n)` is larger than `log(log(n))`. So you should expect the complexity of `digitalRoot` to be at least `log(n)`, certainly not `log(log(n))`.

Comment: Got it!, thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

## Let's calculate the complexity for the first step

If an algorithm depends on the number of digits it contains the time complexity of such algorithm is:

**O(log<sub>10</sub>(n))**

This is because we represent numbers in base 10 notation.
For example, this would make the relation crystal clear:

> O(log<sub>10</sub>(100)) = 2

> O(log<sub>10</sub>(1000)) = 3

> O(log<sub>10</sub>(10000)) = 4

Now this answers the question to some extent, **if we were only adding all digits once, we'd stop here.**

But since we're not, let's move forward. Now if all the digits are added once, we again add the digits of that resultant number. Making it a convergent series.

Thus the **answer** could be:

> **O(log<sub>10</sub>(n)) + O(log<sub>10</sub>(log<sub>10</sub>(n))) + O(log<sub>10</sub>(log<sub>10</sub>(log<sub>10</sub>(n)))) + ...**

This is my best estimation for the upper bound of complexity.

Comment: This is not an infinite sum; `log(log(log(...)))` becomes `1` very quickly. So the complexity is `O(log(n)) + k(n) * O(log(log(n)))` where `k(n)` is the number of iterations until `ans <= 9`. You can expect `k(n)` to be extremely small, but a gross upper bound is: `k(n) <= log(log(n))`. Hence the complexity is `O(log(n) + (log(log(n)))^2)`, which is just `O(log(n))`.

Comment: Also note that there is no point in specifying the base for the logarithm once it is inside `O( )`: for any two bases `a` and `b`, `log_a(x) = log_b(x) / log_b(a)`, and hence `log_a(n) == O(log_b(n))`.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This relationship between different log bases becomes more apparent when `log_a(b)` is an integer; for instance, log_256 gives the number of bytes to represent a number, and log_16 gives the number of "hex digits" (also called *nibbles*) to represent a number; log_16(256) = 2, so it takes twice as many hex digits to represent a number as it takes bytes; log_2(256) = 8, so it takes 8 times as many bits to represent a number in binary as it takes bytes; if you group the bits by 8, you get the bytes; if you group the bits by 4, get the nibbles; group the nibbles by 2, get the bytes.

Comment: logarithms are so fascinating and scary at the same time.. Not mentioning base in O(...) because we can take it out, never even occurred to me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest digital root algorithm:
`def digitalRoot(n): return (n-1) % 9 + 1` 
It is a constant time algorithm, as addition, subtraction, and modulo operations are constant time operations. So digitalRoot calculations can be done in constant time but the algorithm you provided is not the most efficient representation of the operation. Subtracting 1 and adding it back is done to handle the case where n itself is a multiple of 9. In such cases, if we simply take n modulo 9, we would get a result of 0, which is not a single digit. By subtracting 1, we get a value of n-1 which is not a multiple of 9. Then, when we take the modulo 9 of this value, we get a result between 0 and 8, which corresponds to the single-digit numbers between 1 and 9.

For example, if n=9, then n-1=8. When we take 8 modulo 9, we get a result of 8, which is a valid single digit. Similarly, if n=18, then n-1=17. When we take 17 modulo 9, we get a result of 8, which is again a valid single digit.

By adding back 1 to the result of the modulo operation, we shift the range of possible results from [0,8] to [1,9], which corresponds to the valid single digit numbers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer looks pretty solid, but I'd recommend adding code fences around your math expressions just to make them stand out a bit.